# TSQL adding strings together and injection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-injection

How do I add double quotes to a SQL parameter variable (SQL Server 2008 R2) in a stored procedure safely?

I have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1 (@var1 NVARCHAR(100))
AS

DECLARE @var2 NVARCHAR(100);
SET @var2 = '"' + @var1 + '"';

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(col1, @var2);

END
```

So is my `SET @var2` statement vulnerable to SQL injection? Is there a recommended way of adding strings together?

Comment: A stored procedure in not vulnerable to an injection attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine.

Issues with concatenating quotes and SQL injection only arise when you are doing so to create a SQL statement that you then `EXEC`-ute in some manner.

Concatenating them to a variable that is not itself concatenated into a SQL statement is not a SQL injection issue. The variable `@var2` is treated as data rather than executable code throughout.